# Mass of the body M, Cartesian reference frame.

Tags: calculus, vectors

Oxyz is a Cartesian frame of reference with unit base vectors, $i,j$ and $k$.
A rigid body $V$, of uniform density $p$, is bounded by the surfaces
$y=(1-x^2)^{(1/2)}, z=0, y=0$ and $z=1-y$
If the mass of the body is $M$, show that
$M= \frac{p(3\pi -4)}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

In the $x y$ plane, 
$$y=(1-x^2)^{(1/2)}$$

is 
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1 $$

... the circle of unit radius centred at the origin.

So the body is a right prism along the $z$ axis with a semi-circular section.

- To find its volume, multiply its cross-sectional area by its height.
- To find its mass, multiply this by its density.